# What is the difference between normal and bom dependencies in pom.xml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, dependency-management, maven-dependency

I see on maven repository, there are two types of dependencies while I was trying to add into my pom.xml of springBoot Application.
artifactId = aws-java-sdk and aws-java-sdk-bom

What's is the difference between the normal one and the one with the "bom". How do we know which one is a better fit for our requirement?

Answer (score 0):

From the Maven guide:

> Imports are most effective when used for defining a "library" of related artifacts that are generally part of a multiproject build. It is fairly common for one project to use one or more artifacts from these libraries. However, it has sometimes been difficult to keep the versions in the project using the artifacts in synch with the versions distributed in the library. The pattern below illustrates how a "bill of materials" (BOM) can be created for use by other projects.

Read more here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms